# Can we inject a different voice into bark ai model

Tags: python, audio, text-to-speech, voice

[this code is from bark colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eJfA2XUa-mXwdMy7DoYKVYHI1iTd9Vkt?usp=sharing#scrollTo=NyYQ--3YksJY)

```
import torch
from bark import SAMPLE_RATE, generate_audio, preload_models
from IPython.display import Audio

preload_models()

text_prompt = """
     Hello, my name is Suno. And, uh — and I like pizza. [laughs] 
     But I also have other interests such as playing tic tac toe.
"""
audio_array = generate_audio(text_prompt)
Audio(audio_array, rate=SAMPLE_RATE)
```

this works but I need to create a video in that a dog is a narrator, so I need to make the voice sound like a dog's voice (maybe changing equalization, formant shifting, pitch setting). All the tools I tried on the internet, there is no such option, you can only use pre-existing voices. So I thought maybe I could create on my own so found `bark` which considered to be the most advance text-to-speech model

I tried to change the template to say that it is a dog and likes dog-related things, but the voice is still a human voice.